# How to get execution status of asynchronous Snowflake query by query id?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am executing an asynchronous query against Snowflake and getting back a query_id.  I want to query Snowflake to determine the execution status of the query, so I will know when it is safe to retrieve the results.  What is the best way to do this?  I am ruling out the below methods, as they each have limitations.

QUERY_HISTORY Function - I only want the status for 1 query.  This function returns multiple queries, which is inefficient.  Additionally, it has a row limit, so if my query was more than 10,000 queries ago, it will not be returned.  Also, the bigger value I set for result_limit, the longer the function takes to run.  A call with the value of 100 took 5 seconds to complete, while a value of 10,000 took multiple minutes, before I gave up and aborted the query.

QUERY_HISTORY View - The documentation states that this view has up to a 45 minute latency in data.  I need to know the status in real time.

Comment: What tool/library/mechanism are you using to submit the asynchronous request? The Snowflake documentation has lots of examples about how to get a query status e.g. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#checking-the-status-of-a-query

Comment: @NickW - I am aware that the Python and Java libraries offer asynchronous queries natively, but the .Net library does not, so I am trying to build a work around.

Comment: @Eric Maybe  [Snowflake SQL API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/reference.html#post-api-statements) could be an option(using async parameter) and it should be agnostic to used library.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - I put some effort into using SQL API, but could not find any documentation to help me get going with it from .Net.  I even posted a question on it that has received no reply (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70759291/looking-for-example-of-using-snowflake-rest-sql-api-in-net).  The official .Net Driver already has the authentication problem solved, so if I can just come up with a simple Snowflake SQL query that provides query status from an id, this whole thing will be a lot easier.

Comment: The result limit is not 1,000, but rather 10,000. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html#:~:text=the%20specified%20limit.-,Range%3A%201%20to%2010000,-Default%3A%20100.

Comment: @PhilCoulson - 10,000 is still a limitation.  This is an enterprise system where I expect a lot of queries to be happening.  Plus, if I actually set the parameter to the full 10,000, then the function takes even longer, as it has to fetch and return that many records before I get a chance to filter on query id.

Comment: @PhilCoulson - I ran the query with result_limit => 100, and that took 5 seconds to run.  I then tried with it set to 10,000.  The query has been running for over 2 minutes, and is still going, so just increasing the result_limit does not seem like a viable option.

Comment: @Eric What query did you run? Did you not have a where clause to filter on a specific query_id? Querying the entire query_history will obviously take more time?

Comment: @PhilCoulson - as stated in my original question, there are two types of query_history.  One is a view and one is a function.  The view has a 45 minute lag, so it is out of the question.  The function does not accept a query_id argument.  The only option is to call the function and then filter the results afterward.  Because of this, the where filter does not get applied until after the function returns all of the records it is going to fetch, and the more records I fetch, the longer it takes to run.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to run

```
select *
from table(information_schema.query_history())
where query_id = ?
```

Comment: As I stated in my initial question, the query_history function returns a set number or rows.  If the database has had enough new queries since I started mine, it will not be returned by the function.

Comment: This actually looks like a viable solution to me. @Eric I think the row limit is for the output, so it doesn't matter how many queries were in between as long as they were run in the last 7 days. If you want to speed things up, you could `query_history_by_user` or even more specific `query_history_by_session`. By default they assume current user and session resp.

Comment: @PhilCoulson - "RESULT_LIMIT: A number specifying the maximum number of rows returned by the function: If the number of matching rows is greater than this limit, the queries with the most recent end time (or those that are still executing) are returned, up to the specified limit.  Range: 1 to 10000"  This is an enterprise system.  What happens when there have been more than 10000 queries since I started the one I want?